# Back button causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I pass parameters from MainActivity to Acivity2 by using

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Then I have a back button from FinalActivity to Activity2. --> Error occurs

I know it is because this line, because I didn't pass any parameter from FinalActivity to Activity2, but I'm not quiet sure how to fix this.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

Here is the code for back button.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? It sounds like you know what the problem is. The easiest fix would be to just wrap the line in a null check.

Comment: Check if `Intent` is `null` before this line

Comment: I just want to create a simple back button. go to previous page. I do play around with the parameter when from MainActivity to Activity2. So if check Intent==null. My function will through errors.

Comment: How will it throw errors?

Comment: My bad. Not error,but new problem.My program works like this.Pass Parameters from MainActivity to Activity2 and then to FinalActivity. Then click back button from FinalAcitivity to Activity2 makes the parameter null, Now if I click the FinalActivity to go to FinalActivity. It pass the null value to FinalActivity and doesn't display the data

Comment: Check my edited answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't wanting to pass anything back from `FinalActivity` then just use something like

```
if (getIntent() != null)
{
     Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

After your comment, it sounds like you need some more persistent data then what you get with an `Activity`. You can check out [Storage Options Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see what would work best for you. But from what little I know if your needs I would say you could use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) if you want the data to be stored even if you leave your app.

If you only need it to persist through the life of your app then you can create a `static` class and store/ reference the variables there. If you need more help then you will need to provide a more context or examples of what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful. I'm going to try SharedPreferences.